# PHP: Невидимый watermark

Tags: php, watermark

Нужна PHP библиотека\скрипт для нанесения невидимого watermark и его последующего распознавания, есть такое у кого-то?

**UPD.** Покажите кто-то пример, как нанести прозрачный текст на изображении с использованием GD, может быть поможет, вместо невидимого вотермарка

Comment: так что? Никто не может помочь с прозрачным вотермарком?

Comment: Реализаций цифровых водяных знаков на PHP не встречал, уверен, делать придется Вам самому.

По дополненному вопросу — примеры тривиальных поделок с нанесением текста или картинки можно найти тут: http://www.ivankristianto.com/web-development/programming/image-watermarking-using-php/1485/

Answer (score 1):

Невидимые глазу метки ставят, в частности, с использованием модификации [наименее значащего бита](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=наименее+значащий+бит). Не нашёл готового php класса, но можете попробовать реализовать самостоятельно. Смысл в том, что каждая точка описывается 8-битным значением цвета в каждом из трёх каналов. Замена самого младшего бита так незначительно меняет оттенок, что глазу это точно незаметно. Таким образом, можно внедрить в картинку некое осмысленное сообщение, модифицируя младшие биты.

Надо только предусмотреть, что изображение могут уменьшать, сжимать jpeg'ом с жутким качеством, и т.п. Поэтому поинтересуйтесь ещё устройством [QR кодов](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=QR+код), и алгоритмах защиты от ошибок, которые в них используются. Объединив QR и LSB (*англ.* least significant bit), можете написать собственную реализацию весьма надежного watermarking'а картинок.

Comment: Попробовать можно, но лучше что-то искать конкретно под JPEG-формат. Так как в ходе преобразования цветовой модели и косинус-преобразования (ну а пессимистичном варианте ещё и усреднения значений) - младшие биты разбегуться кто-куда. Единственное, что можно попробовать - это писать во все три цвета одно значение, тогда во-первых при смене модели оно попадет в канал яркости, а его коверкают меньше, чем хроматические, во вторых это будет ещё маленькая дополнительная коррекция ошибок (по двум одинаковым из трех).

Comment: Плюс куча информации для восстановления + многократное повторение записи. Тогда, возможно ваша стенограмма переживет jpeg-компрессор)

Answer (score -2):

Не знаю на счёт библиотеки (и вообще о создании невидимого ватермарка), но если Вам нужно как-то помечать картинки, может быть будет удобнее использовать [**`EXIF`**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXIF)-метаданные, что [более правдоподобно](https://github.com/lsolesen/pel/), нежели невидимый *Ватермарк*.

Comment: exif данные при конвертации картинки запросто вычищаются, да и не только при конвертации. Автору видимо нужно сохранить "права" на картинку.

Comment: Ну, тогда невидимый ватермарк тоже бессмыслен, что мешает на Windows "ножницами" сделать копию картинки ;)

Comment: @lampa, что видимый, что невидимый ватермарк с этой точки зрения - фигня полная. Банальное пересохранение картинки, что вручную, что автопилотным скриптом из паука, что вообще принтскрином, и никакого ватермарка нет.

Comment: Покажите кто-то пример, как нанести прозрачный текст на изображении с использованием GD, может быть поможет, вместо невидимого вотермарка

Comment: @phpmvv, этим Вы ни чего не добьетесь...

Comment: Ну уже лучше, чем ничего.
Доступ к картинкам будет иметь узкий круг людей, на изображение будет наноситься уникальный ключ по которому можно будет узнать кто его просматривал, и закрыть доступ этому пользователю, если эта картинка всплывет на другом сайте. Если использовать прозрачный вотермарк+ EXIF-метаданные, и блокировку правой кнопки мыши(от совсем не опытных пользователей), то вполне возможно, что это будет достаточно. Поэтому всё-таки покажите пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: @phpmvv, проще всего заранее приготовить файл с ватермарком, и вклеивать его в ваши картинки. Примеры найдёте в любом руководстве. Но нужно понимать, что это или просто бесплезно, или бесполезно ПЛЮС будет уродовать картинки, третьего не дано.

Comment: Дело в том, что вотермарк всегда уникальный.

Comment: Значит, генертие уникальный ватермарк - мы ж тут не телепаты что и как вы хотите сделать :) Вы ж сами фактически рассказываете что нужно сделать, так делайте, от нас-то что в этом случае нужно?

Comment: Сделал-то я все, дело не в этом. Мне нужен пример, как нанести прозрачный текст на изображение, именно прозрачный.

Comment: Чушь несете про «ножницы». Цифровой водяной знак будет очевидно устойчив к «принтскрину» (который вообще не меняет пиксели). Хороший водяной знак будет устойчив и к пересжатию (до определенного предела, разумеется), т.к. даже после, скажем, ресайза + DCT (для JPEG), в частотном, например, пространстве останутся характерные искажения, по которым можно будет его детектировать.

Comment: @drdaeman, хроший водяной знак это такой, который не уродует картинку, и не идёт поперёк изображения. А очень скромно занимает крохотный участок около кромки :) Убирается он элементарно. Но в любом случае рецепт тот же: просто наложить заранее подготовленную картинку со знаком куда хочется. [Например](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=watermark&go_search=1)

Comment: Если уж заявлен вопрос о _невидимых_ вотермарках, то понятно что дело идет не о визуально читаемой надписи на изображении, а о стеганографической защите. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermarking

Правда, повторюсь, реализаций на PHP я никогда не встречал, и Google солидарен в молчании (хотя делают же, например, БПФ на PHP). Помнится, видел раньше что-то на Java, но сейчас как-то не найти с ходу.